# regex to match ending of specific function call

Tags: regex

I have a function sqlCall(a,b,c....); It has unknown no. of parameters.
I need a regex to match the ending of the function ); or ; and add a string there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I've tried (?s)(?<=sqlCall)(.*?)(?=;), but it returns (a,b,c....) and I need to add text after the ending parenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
/sqlCall\([^\)]+(\);)/${1}somestring/
```

$1 is the first matching group - in that case ");"

Comment: I have a problem, I'm using notepad++ for this, the regex sqlCall\([^\)]+(\);) matches what I'm looking for, but how can I get $1 in notepad++ or what should I fill on the replace with input. Thanks.

Comment: In that case: 
Find what: (sqlCall\([^\)]+)(\);)
Replace with:" $1 something ); "

Comment: I managed to solve this thanks! (_sqlCall \([^\)]+)(\);)

 

And i replace with \1”string wich i whant”;

Comment: Or if You want to append something after ");"   replace with "$1);something"